# ADB wifi unreachable when it looses connection in device with wake lock (CPU only)?

Tags: android, adb, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I am using wake lock on my Nexus 4 to force it to stay awake (I am using wake lock with CPU only option). However, after sometime, ADB wifi looses connecting and I am unable to reconnect to it again unless I turn the screen back on.

Does anyone know solution to this problem? I have the need to keep the screen off, while still be able to access phone via ADB wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You need a wifi lock - check the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html). In short, the CPU lock won't keep the wifi radio on too - you need a separate (wifi) lock for that.